# jQuery div fade text only, keep the div

Tags: jquery, fade

I have a div in which I display an error message. After the error message is displayed, I want to fade it out but keep the div in which it appeared. I only want the text of the error message to fade out not the div and the text. Currently, I have my code like this and the div fades as well as the text and I was wondering what change I need to get the effect I want:

```
if ($("#chseFile").val() == "") {
        $("#uploadErrors").text("You must select a file to upload.");
        $("#uploadErrors").show();
        $("#uploadErrors html").fadeOut(3000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if ($("#chseFile").val() == "") {
    $("#uploadErrors").html("<span class='text'>You must select a file to upload.</span>");
    $("#uploadErrors").show();
    $("#uploadErrors .text").fadeOut(3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On fadeout defaultly css set display none so you want add another child for the parent div

```
if ($("#chseFile").val() == "") {

        $("#uploadErrors").append("<span>You must select a file to upload.</span>")
        $("#uploadErrors").show();
        $("#uploadErrors span").fadeOut(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// if uploadErrors div is by default hidden  
if ($("#chseFile").val() == "")  
{  
 $("#uploadErrors").html("<span>You must select a file to upload.</span>"); 
 $("#uploadErrors").show().find('span').fadeOut(3000);
  }

/* if by default not hidden then */

if ($("#chseFile").val() == "") {

        $("#uploadErrors").html("<span>You must select a file to upload.</span>");
        $("#uploadErrors span").fadeOut(3000);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text()` property and use `fadeOut` on that instead of the div itself:

```
if ($("#chseFile").val() == "") {
        $("#uploadErrors").text("You must select a file to upload.");
        $("#uploadErrors").show();
        $("#uploadErrors html").text().fadeOut(3000);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can not fade out only text. What you can do is take another div and wrap your error message. Than you can fade out inner div. Like this...

```
<div> //You don't want to fade out this div
    <div class="error">error message here</div>  // fade out this div
</div>
```

Comment: Why downvote? What i mean is if he want to fade out only text than why he is not fading out div. If div contains some other info than with text fade out other text also will goes...